# Weinman AIF and High temporal resolution AIF difference

Tags: mri

I'm dealing with MRI DCE maps. Actually I need to find such parameters as the transfer constant $K^{trans}$ and rate constant $k^{ep}$ according to the two-compartment model.
Mathematically, this dynamic system can be described by the following equation:
$$C_t(t)=DK^{trans} \sum\limits_{i=1}^2 a_i [exp(-k^{ep}t) - exp(-m_it)]/[m_i-k_{ep}]$$
Now if I have contrast agent concentration $C_t(t)$ time series from experiment I can extract transfer constant $K^{trans}$, and rate constant $k^{ep}$ by least square fitting. The only problem is that I need to know $a_i$ and $m_i$ constants. For this purpose I use the next formula for blood plasma concentration: $$c_p(t)=D \sum\limits_{i=1}^2 a_i exp(-m_it)$$
However I can't find the relation between the blood plasma concentration: $c_p(t)$ and $c_t(t)$. In the next article:
 Geoff J.M. Parker et. al. "Experimentally-Derived Functional Form for a Population-Averaged High-Temporal-Resolution Arterial Input Function for Dynamic Contrast-Enhanced MRI"
I have found that biexponential function $c_p(t)$ is used to describe AIF (arterial input function). It's presented on plot as Weinmann AIF.

[image: rectangles]

QUESTIONS:

1) How Weinman AIF and High temporal resolution AIF can describe the same processes, actually from mathematical point of view it's two completely different functions?

2) Do I really can find $a_i$ and $m_i$ parameters by fitting AIF curve with $C_p(t)$ function?

P.S. I'm just a programmer so I completely unaware in the field of biology and any help is appreciated.